# location issues for the custom roms like Miui,Oppo,Vivo etc

Tags: location, miui, oppo

Guys i am facing an issue regading the location updates on Custom Roms like Miui,Oppo etc,
These Roms are taking too much time for location update and in background it do not trigger the listner, and in foreground it takes about 1-2 minutes to get fine location,

i want to minimize this time to 5-10 seconds, Please let me know what can be done.

By the way thanks in advance

Comment: Did you test that on stock ROMs the GPS works better? Are you developing an app or just using your phone's location in other apps? Do you want to optimize your code or get tips to help your phone find location faster?

Comment: yes i tested on stock rom and it works perfect